# Matrix Multiplication/Addition Very Slow on GPU in Certain Cases

Tags: performance, matlab, gpu

I'm currently trying to get my code to run on my GPU, instead of CPU - well, it is running, but not well. Let me give the relevant parts of the code:

```
u = zeros(n*L,1  ,'gpuArray'); ubar = zeros(n*L,1  ,'gpuArray');
y = zeros(n*L*d,1,'gpuArray'); ybar = zeros(n*L*d,1,'gpuArray');
v = zeros(n*L*d,1,'gpuArray');
w = zeros(n,1    ,'gpuArray');
z = zeros(n*L*d,1,'gpuArray');

...

    v_arg = v + sigma * (D * ubar - T_t * ybar);   (1)
    w_arg = w + sigma * Q * ubar;
    z_arg = z + sigma * ybar;

    v_new = back.dual.v(v_arg,w_arg,z_arg);
    w_new = back.dual.w(v_arg,w_arg,z_arg);
    z_new = back.dual.z(v_arg,w_arg,z_arg);

    u_arg = u - tau * (D_t * v_new + Q_t * w_new);   (2)
    y_arg = y - tau * (z_new - T * v_new);

    u_new = back.prim.u(u_arg,y_arg);
    y_new = back.prim.y(u_arg,y_arg);

    ubar_new = u_new + theta*(u_new - u);
    ybar_new = y_new + theta*(y_new - y);

...

% The dimensions of the matrices are as follows:
% D is (n*L*d,n*L); T is (n*L*d,n*L*d); Q is (n,n*L).

% Finally, "_t" denotes the transpose of a matrix. I found that it is a lot
% faster to define a new matrix that is the transpose, instead of doing the
% transpose operation each time.
```

The two labelled equations - (1) and (2) - are the bottlenecks. Please see the following image for the times taken on one of my runs. [image: GPU Times].

Lastly, the matrices are sparse matrices - I'm using Matlab 2015a, so it's fine with sparse matrices on the GPU (2014b doesn't like them). The characteristic sizes of the parameters are as follow: `n = 60^2 = 3600, L = 48, d = 2`.

Here are the corresponding times for the CPU. Please note that the number of times called is nearly 20 times as many, which is why some of the times are actually longer.

[image: CPU Times]

Interesting, I think, how the efficiency of different lines varies when comparing the CPU and GPU. The final line is slightly faster on the GPU, but the penultimate line is about 6 times slower on the GPU and the first line about 20 times slower on the GPU.

If any more information is required, then please let me know.

---

Below is an MVCE:

```
N = [50,50];
n = prod(N); d = numel(N);
L = 64;

sigma = 0.1;
tau   = 0.1;

D = spdiags([-ones(n*L*d,1), ones(n*L*d,1)],0:1,n*L*d,n*L);
D_t = D';

T = spdiags([-ones(L*d,1), ones(L*d,1)],0:1,L*d,L*d);
T = kron(T,speye(n));
T_t = T';

Q = sparse(n,n*L);
for j = 1:L
    Q(:,1+(j-1)*n:j*n) = speye(n); %#ok<SPRIX>
end
Q_t = Q';

u = zeros(n*L,1  ,'gpuArray');
y = zeros(n*L*d,1,'gpuArray');
v = zeros(n*L*d,1,'gpuArray');
w = zeros(n,1    ,'gpuArray');
z = zeros(n*L*d,1,'gpuArray');

count = 0;
count_max = 1000;   % Choose count_max as the maximum number of iterations
while count <= count_max
    v = v + sigma * (D * u - T_t * y);
    w = w + sigma * Q * u;
    z = z + sigma * y;

    u = u - tau * (D_t * v + Q_t * w);
    y = y - tau * (z - T * v);

    count = count + 1;

    if mod(count,10) == 0
        fprintf('count = %1g\n',count)
    end
end
```

Comment: When measuring performance, you usually include the data sizes.  What is the size of your matrices before invoking each line?  That's important.  We can't tell what's wrong unless you give us more information about how to reconstruct your problem.  All we have is your code.  Can you provide sample inputs for each variable so that we can assess your problem further?

Comment: Oops, yeah, forgot to put size of the parameters in! I'll just update now.

Comment: Anything else you need? :)

Comment: Would it be possible to provide sample inputs for each matrix so that your example is a MVCE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  It would help if we could actually reproduce your results to find your error.  As of now, the reason why the runtime is larger for those two lines could be anything.

Comment: Also, did you try using CPU based arrays and running the computation and comparing results?  Is the CPU version faster or slower than the GPU version?

Comment: Ok, I shal have a look at doing that. FIrstly, in response to your second comment, yes, I did. CPU is much faster because it doesn't have this bottleneck - the time is spread between the lines much more as I would expect (related to the number of matrix*vector operations and their relative sizes). I've added another picture showing the times; note that they're all larger than the ones above, but look at the number of time that the lines have been called: 4200 compared with 226, 18.6 times as many.

Comment: Ah, I think I've found it! I made D, Q and T GPU arrays, but D_t, Q_t and T_t were still doubles! I'll confirm in a moment if that was the only problem.

Comment: Gotta love [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :).

Comment: Yeah, I know! I'm not really a programmer, but a mathematician, and it's the same when I'm doing maths problems! Sometimes I'll even talk to someone who has no idea what I'm talking about, and then it helps me sort it out!

Comment: There's now no bottleneck... it's just twice as fast on my CPU as GPU! I am only on a laptop though, and I've got a proper (getting slightly old, now) gaming graphics card at home, so I'll try it on that, but I wouldn't expect it to double the comparative speed (especially as I've got a similar standard processor).

Comment: Alright! Well let me know how that goes.  I didn't know that `D_t`, `Q_t` and `T_t` were still `double` arrays... if I saw the entire code, I would have pointed that out.  You'd be surprised actually... modern laptops now have pretty decent GPUs!

Comment: Ah yeah, I even forgot to put in the mini-code the GPU conversion! Criminal! - What should I do with this question? It doesn't really enhance SO, as no-one else will have this exact question

Comment: There are two things you can do: (1) Delete your question, (2) Answer your own question.  I think it does enhance SO because it will tell people to make sure that all of your arrays are `gpuArray`s!  It is a common bug that many people encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The issue was that while I was assigning the matrices to the GPU, I was defining a new matrix `D_t` as the transpose - this is so that I didn't have to take the transpose of the matrix on the GPU every time, and so saved loads of time - I wasn't assigning the transpose-matrix to the GPU!

As rayryeng pointed out, the moral of this is **make sure all your arrays are `gpuArray`!** Hopefully my mistake will stop other people from making the same mistake! :)

Comment: One other potential source of difference in performance is that `gpuArray` sparse matrices are stored in CSR format; MATLAB's native sparse format is CSC. These perform very differently depending on whether you are transposing the arguments. It is _usually_ better to let MATLAB see when you are doing something like `A' * B` (i.e. rather than doing `At = A'; C = At * B`) as it can sometimes perform better in that case - but not always, as you observe (this can be due to the CSR/CSC format differences).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the insight. To be honest, I don't actually know what the CSR and CSC formats are; I just found *in my particular case* that it was immeasurably faster (metaphorically!) to define the transpose matrix first.

Comment: It's still actually pretty slow, on both the GPU and CPU. When computing the product `A*x` of a sparse matrix and a full vector, does Matlab compute it "intelligently"? By this, I means does it only take the elements of the vector which will be multiplied by non-zero components? I was trying to think of a way to speed it up, but my matrix is very sparse - it has at most two non-zero entries per row (a `-1` and a `1`), and is in the region of `6400 by 6400`.

Comment: The details of the MATLAB SpMV (sparse matrix-vector product) are opaque - MATLAB generally uses existing high-quality numeric libraries for this sort of building block of algebra, so it is reasonable to assume that the structure of your sparse matrix is considered.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I can make the multiplication massively faster - even 50 times faster - by writing the matrix-vector product explicitly when the parameters are small, but when they start to get large it's faster using the matrix product. Thanks for your help. :)